# 'ng build' aborted - Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, node-modules

Trying to run ng build so that I can get my /dist folder to host on a remote server.
I've run npm install just fine, however running ng build is not working - it aborts every time.

This is what it says:

```
ng build[3725390]: ../src/node_worker.cc:525:static void node::worker::Worker::StartThread(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&): Assertion `(uv_thread_create_ex(&w->tid_, &thread_options, [](void* arg) { Worker* w = static_cast<Worker*>(arg); const uintptr_t stack_top = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&arg); w->stack_base_ = stack_top - (kStackSize - kStackBufferSize); w->Run(); Mutex::ScopedLock lock(w->mutex_); w->on_thread_finished_.Stop(); }, static_cast<void*>(w))) == (0)' failed.
 1: 0x9aedf0 node::Abort() [ng build]
 2: 0x9aee77  [ng build]
 3: 0xa422cc  [ng build]
 4: 0xb8df76  [ng build]
 5: 0xb8fe97 v8::internal::Builtin_HandleApiCall(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [ng build]
 6: 0x13162b9  [ng build]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Node version -v12.6.0
Angular version -8.2.2

Thanks

Comment: There should be some more information in the console...

Comment: That's all it says before it terminates. There's nothing after aborted (core dumped). How do I see the extra info?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following command.

`node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --build-optimizer`

Comment: Why have people added -1s for this question? Is it safe to run?